# What type of feed would you like to have on our chat room?

Tags: discussion

Until recently, new questions were posted on our chat room as regular messages (by a generic user called Stack Exchange). As such, they were persistent and remained on the chat history forever. Some users found it annoying, so I decided to enable another way of feeding new questions to our chat. This is what SE calls "Ticker feeds" with wich new questions "will be shown via a slide-down ticker overlay that periodically appears at the top of the room, and will not be persisted."

But I'd like to know what most users think about it and then choose based on their opinion. Even though the chat regulars are few and the decision could be made informally, I think a formal poll is a more open and transparent way of handling it. So, feel free to vote up or down on the type of feed you'd like to have on our chat room.

Comment: Is this specific to all SE or just Linguistics? Is it a parameter per site (and if so, what are the choices)?

Comment: Hi, @Mitch. This poll was intended only for Linguistics.SE, as each site has its own configuration. The options are the two answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Message feeds

New items from these feeds will be posted into the room like regular chat messages.

Comment: I prefer this method, because it enables me to read part of the question immediately, not just the title. As to clutter, I don't really find that a problem, since we are not exactly swamped in questions. A few questions a day makes our site perfect for this.

Comment: Me toooooooooo.

Comment: After one week, this option won by 4 x 1.

Answer (score 4):

### Ticker feeds

New items from these feeds will be shown via a slide-down ticker overlay that periodically appears at the top of the room, and will not be persisted.